# Garbage in the output of a print to screen statement

Tags: assembly, x86

Like the title says, my print procedure is outputting garbage for some reason. Here's the proc definition:

```
print proc near
 mov ah, 09h
 int 21h
 ret
print endp
```

And here's where it gets called in my code:

```
emptyTail:
 mov dl, offset standardError
 call print
 jmp quit
```

Here's standardError:

```
standardError db "Sorry we ran into an error. Try again", 13,10, "$"
```

The other parts of the code work fine but once this particular branch is called, it spits out a bunch of weird characters. Any idea why?

Comment: `dh` probably has incorrect value and so the output is something you didn't expect. It should be `mov dx, offset standardError`.

Comment: thanks @nrz. It's still giving me the weird bunch of characters, only this time it's like:  4878rygu3ilht83hu43ry783494948u704 Sorry we ran into an error.Try again

Comment: You probably have incorrect value is `ds` too. The string address is given in `ds:dx`.

Comment: ok@nrz that makes sense. Is there a way I can clear out the values in the `ds:dx` register

Comment: "Is there a way I can clear out the values in the `code` ds:dx register" Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry lol i was trying to format the `ds:dx` part, fixed it now. I mean is there a way that I can make sure there is no value in `ds` or `dx` so I don't get any garbage in the output?

Comment: "there is no value in `ds` or `dx`". That does not make sense. All registers have always some value. You'll get garbage in the output if you have garbage in the input.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is obvious but could you explain how you would remove the garbage if you were in my shoes?

Comment: After these obvious fixes I would single-step the code in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put DX with the offset of your string. DS is probably pointing already to your segment data, isn't it? Is it a COM or a EXE file what you're making? If it's a COM, DS is already set.

```
emptyTail:
 mov dx, offset standardError   ;DX, not DL or DH.
 call print
 jmp quit
```